# UseEffect fails to trigger after useQuerry

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've simplified my component with the relevant bits. Basically a gql query that gets some data and when the data is in, it should be saved in a context(`setLobbyData`).

The `console.log` are there to help me figure it out but I don't really understand why the `useEffect` doesn't gets triggered after the data is fetched, as can be observed from the logs

```
const LobbySection = ({ route, navigation }: Props) => {
  const params = route.params;

  const lobbyDataQuery = useQuery<GetGame, GetGameVariables>(GET_LOBBY_DATA, {
    variables: { gameId: params.id },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    pollInterval: 5000,
  });
  console.log('OOOOOO', lobbyDataQuery.data)

  const { refetch, data, error } = lobbyDataQuery;

  useEffect(() => {
    setLobbyData(data);
    console.log('%%%%%%%%Data', data)
  }, [data])

  useEffect(() => { console.log('{{{{{{{', isFocused, lobbyDataQuery.error)
    if (isFocused) {
      refetch();
      lobbyDataQuery.startPolling(5000);
      console.log('XXXXXXXXXXXXsetLobbyData', lobbyDataQuery.data)
      setLobbyData(data);
    }
  }, [data, isFocused, refetch]);
}
```

The logs look like

```
LOG  OOOOOO undefined
 LOG  %%%%Data undefined
 LOG  {{{{{{{ true undefined
 LOG  XXXXXXXXXXXXsetLobbyData undefined
 LOG  OOOOOO undefined
 LOG  OOOOOO undefined
LOG  OOOOOO {"checkedIn": 0, "filteredRankingForGame": [], "game": {"__typename": "Game", "courts": [[Object], [Object], [Object]], "date": "2023-09-13T09:04:36.577380+00:00", "endingTime": "2023-09-13T09:03:55.150+00:00", "extraInfo": "Qwert", "finished": false, "gameCode": "834 502", "gameLocation": "Moon", "gameMaker": 9286, "gameMakerName": "boo", "gameName": "Wawy", "gameStarted": false, "gameType": "random", "id": 11947, "numberOfBalls": 24, "numberOfPlayers": 12, "numberOfRounds": 0, "occasionId": null, "players": [[Object]], "reservePlayers": [], "reserveTeams": [], "startingTime": "2023-09-13T09:03:55.150+00:00", "teams": [], "totalNumberOfRounds": 8}, "gameCompanyBrand": null, "gameMessages": [], "isCheckedIn": false, "isGameMaker": true, "isInGame": true, "isInGameReserve": false, "team": null, "teamsAreFilled": null, "user": {"__typename": "User", "id": 9286}}
 LOG  vv {}
```

so at some point the data comes in, but the `useEffect` that has a dependency on either `data` or `lobbyDataQuery` gets triggered, the `vv` part is from a child component. At this point I'm questioning if I truly understand how useEffect is supposed to work. I didn't find any side effects for when it is used together with graphQL, perhaps I'm missing something quite obvious?

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing because it looks like it should work. Are are you sure `data` itself is not conflicting with another variable with the same name?

Might be worth just trying

`const { refetch, data, error } = useQuery<GetGame, GetGameVariables>(GET_LOBBY_DATA...`

then using that data as the dependency on in your useEffect.

If that doesn't work maybe you can just try the `onCompleted` option.

```
  const lobbyDataQuery = useQuery<GetGame, GetGameVariables>(GET_LOBBY_DATA, {
    variables: { gameId: params.id },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    pollInterval: 5000,
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setLobbyData(data);
      console.log('%%%%%%%%Data', data)
    },
  });
```

Ill admit your code does look like it should work though, again..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did try it but with no change. I also tried using `onCompleted ` and `onError` but none are logging anything, which is suspicious